# Loopback Operation hook receives options as empty

Tags: loopback

I'll try to explain this weird situation as simple as I can.

I've created an operation hook `"before save"` and make it in a `mixin` to add it to some models.

this mixin uses `context.options` to get current `userId` to do something.

this mixin is working perfectly if I call the operation directly (like `POST /Accounts` for example).

But if I call it inside a remote method, the context.options is empty, for example, if we have a method called `POST /Accounts/Signup`, and inside it, we call `Account.create(...)`, the `"before save"` hook receives the `options` as `empty object {}`

**A sandbox project has been hosted here** 
https://github.com/mustafamagdy/loopback-sandbox-issue

the mixin code snippet is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  Model.observe("before save", async function(ctx) {
    if (ctx.instance.id) return;

    const userId = ctx.options && ctx.options.accessToken && ctx.options.accessToken.userId;

    if (userId) {
      //... do stuff
    }
    else 
    {
      console.error("Failed to scope " + Model.name + " to user (null)");
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation, I found this [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/3023) that talks about similar behaviour, however, the comments are very destractive. So I thoughlt to write the conclusion here for anyone who are facing the same issue.

Loopback require you to pass the options you declared from the remote method to the model method(s) if you want to receive it on operation hook, so I ended up doing so.

```
module.exports = function(Note) {
  Note.makeNew = makeNew;

  async function makeNew(options) {
    await Note.create(obj, options);
  }
};
```